# Is there a way for two different events to be triggered with one mouse action?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

From the example displayed on the [SWING component example index](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TableSelectionDemo) from Oracle called [TableSelectionDemo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableSelectionDemoProject/src/components/TableSelectionDemo.java):

Screenshot of program:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkizq.png]

I noticed that multiple rows can be selected as usual when the click starts from a cell in the first 4 columns, but not when the click starts in the fifth column containing the checkboxes. I'm guessing this is the case because because the event that handles the state of the checkbox is triggered, but this in turn prevents the row selection event from being triggered as well.

Is there a way for regular selection to work through that use case while preserving the regular behaviour regarding the checkboxes?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkizq.png

Comment: Yes, you can make this work by forwarding/passing the click event from the radio button event into your selection event method. This is not how most people would expect it to work however, and may cause other issues with incorrect selections?

Comment: 1) That is not a radio button. That is a check box. Please use proper terminology. 2) Multiple rows are still selected for me. Maybe this is a version/platform issue. I use JDK11 on Windows 10. However, I did notice that the column selection event is not generated when all clicks are done on the column with the check boxes.